# What would the best way be to take a string from a text file and search and replace another string with the one from the text file?

Tags: perl, command-line, vbscript

What would the best way be to take a string from a text file and search and replace another string with the one from the text file?

E.g `c:\output.txt` has `abcd` and `c:\newfile.txt` has `Stack overflow is great`.

I would like to replace `great` with `abcd`.

What would be the best approach to do this?

Comment: @moorecats: Does your `output.txt` hold only one string? Or are there multiple lines with multiple strings?

Comment: Explain "best": "faster run time", "smaller memory usage", "smaller code", "most maintainable code"...
The Perl slogan is "There is more than one way to do it". Depending on your need, the solution is different.

Answer (score 1):

you can download [sed for windows](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/sed.htm) and then

```
set /p var=<output.txt
sed "s/%var%/Stackoverflow is great/g" newfile.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

Since Perl was your first tag, I guess you'd want a Perl version of the solution.

If you have Perl installed on your Windows, the following works (whitespace added for readability):

```
C:\>perl  -e "open(my $rf, '<', 'c:\output.txt') 
                 || die \"Can not open c:\output.txt: $!\"; 
              my $replace = <$rf>; 
              chomp $replace; 
              close $rf; 
              local $^I='.bak'; # Replace inside the file, make backup
              while (<>) {
                  s/great/$replace/g; 
                  print;
    }" c:\newfile.txt

C:\>type C:\newfile.txt
Stack overflow is abcd
```

To be a bit more Windows idiomatic, you can replace the start of the Perl code (reading of the contents of a file) with a "cmd"'s `SET /P` command (see Ghostdog's asnwer), for a much shorter Perl code:

```
C:\> set /p r=<c:\output.txt
C:\> perl  -pi.bak -e "s/great/%r%/g;" c:\newfile.txt

C:\> type C:\newfile.txt
Stack overflow is abcd
```

Comment: @moorecats - welcome. If it was useful, feel free to up-vote (up arrow next to the answer) and accept (the checkmark next to the answer) my answer.